# Как обработать получаемые значения из QTableWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

Есть таблица, куда помещаются цифры типа double и позже по нажатию на различные кнопки происходит поиск минимума, максимума и среднего. И я не понимаю почему, когда я не до конца заполняю таблицу, он все равно считает значения по кнопкам. Как это исправить?

Листинг кода поиска среднего

```c
void Widget::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{

    int size = ui->tableWidget->rowCount();
    double mas[size];
    for (int i = 0; i<size; ++i)
    {
        mas[i] = 0;
    }

    bool ok = false, allok = true;

    for (int i = 0; i<size; ++i)
    {
        QTableWidgetItem *curCell = ui->tableWidget->item(i,0);
        if(curCell!=nullptr)
        {
           mas[i] = curCell->text().toDouble(&ok);
           if(!ok)
           {
               allok = false;
               break;
           }
        }
        else
        {
            curCell = new QTableWidgetItem("");
            curCell->setBackground(Qt::red);

            ui->tableWidget->blockSignals(true);
             ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,0,curCell);
            ui->tableWidget->blockSignals(false);

            allok = false;
        }
    }
    if (ok)
        ui->average->setText("Среднее значение: "+QString::number(Sr(mas,size)));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

ячейки все равно есть, хоть и с пустым значением, поэтому

```
if(curCell!=nullptr)
```

надо заменить на

```
if(!curCell->text().isEmpty())
```